# Xcode 4 error SDK authorize.net

Tags: objective-c

When trying to compile with Xcode, I am getting the following error:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AuthNet", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ConnectionManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using SDK authorize.net

please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't linked the library to your application.  Select the project from the navigator sidebar, select your target, then go to the *Build Phases* section.  Under *Link Binary With Libraries*, add the `AuthNet` library.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not including the libraries correctly.

Make sure that you followed each of these instructions:

```
Set your Library Search Paths with the path that contains the "Authorize.Net SDK" 
library. (ex. "$(SRCROOT)/ANMobilePaymentLib").

Set your Other Linker Flags with "-lxml2" to allow for xml parsing.

Set your Header Search Paths with the path that contains "libxml2" header 
files. (ex. "/usr/include/libxml2" with recursive checked).
```